# Sonos API : service token to play spotify

Tags: sonos

Im using [sonos-objc](https://github.com/getSenic/sonos-objc/) class to control to play songs on sonos

on metadata there is serviceid ("X_#Svc[serviceid]-0-Token")

I read that serviceid = 2311 for EU and serviceid = 3079 for US

is there other service for all world ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Spotify was first introduced on Sonos when it was only available in the EU circa 2008. The US launch of Spotify came about circa 2011. There are licensing differences between the two services.

Comment: And what about other countries that are not in europe and us ?

Comment: [Here](https://support.spotify.com/us/account_payment_help/subscription_options/full-list-of-territories-where-spotify-is-available/) is a list of territories in which Spotify is available. With regard to Sonos, Australia and New Zealand go to the US, while all others go to the EU.